# selenium webdriver seems to be ignoring timeouts

Tags: java, selenium, timeout

I have the following timeouts in the setUp section of my test

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

However none of them seem to be honoured. If i understand correctly, setScriptTimeout should throw an error if there is no action within 60 seconds. This does not seem to be the case. 
Do i need to do something in particular at the start of each @Test in order to enforce these timeouts?

Comment: Well what are you intending to achieve with this? What exactly are you wanting to wait for?

Comment: What i want is that if my script should get stuck looking for an element or something like that, that it should timeout after a period of time. Obviously, asserts in the code will handle failing to find elements, but is there some form of backup timeout I can use in case i miss an assert or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Starting each test with @Test(Timeout = 300000) fixed this. Each test will now timeout if it takes longer than specified.

Comment: for the benefit of python users who end up on this page from a Google search: the pythonic way is ```driver.set_page_load_timeout(99)```